Run time of Kyber in LPC55s69 board
I found a C implementation of a PQC(Post-Quantum Cryptography) algorithm "Kyber" and I wanted to check its run time on a LPC55s69 board. I am checking its runtime in one of the cores of the board. I am a beginner at this and don't know if what I am doing is right. I want to check the run time of key generation.
Would this be a valid way to check the run time of the key generation algorithm?
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "kem.h"
#include "randombytes.h"
#include "fsl_device_registers.h"
#include "fsl_debug_console.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "board.h"
#include "fsl_power.h"
#include "fsl_clock.h"
#include "fsl_systick.h"

#define NTESTS 1000


//key generation
static int test_keys(void)
{
  uint8_t pk[CRYPTO_PUBLICKEYBYTES]; // public key
  uint8_t sk[CRYPTO_SECRETKEYBYTES]; //secret key

 //Alice generates a public key
  crypto_kem_keypair(pk, sk);

  }

  return 0;
}

// Function to initialize the DWT cycle counter
void DWT_Init(void)
{
    // Enable the use of DWT
    CoreDebug->DEMCR |= CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk;
    // Clear the cycle counter
    DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
    // Enable the cycle counter
    DWT->CTRL |= DWT_CTRL_CYCCNTENA_Msk;
}

// Function to get the current cycle count
uint32_t DWT_GetCycles(void)
{
    return DWT->CYCCNT;
}

int main(void){
            BOARD_InitPins();
        BOARD_BootClockPLL150M();
        BOARD_InitDebugConsole();

        SysTick_Init();  // Initialize SysTick
        start_time = SysTick_GetTick();  // Record start time

    // Get the core clock frequency
    uint32_t coreClockFrequency = CLOCK_GetFreq(kCLOCK_CoreSysClk);

    // Print the core clock frequency
    PRINTF("Core clock frequency: %u Hz\r\n", coreClockFrequency);

    // Ensure the core clock frequency is not zero
    if (coreClockFrequency == 0)
    {
        PRINTF("Error: Core clock frequency is zero.\r\n");
        return;
    }

    // Start the cycle counter
    uint32_t start_time = DWT_GetCycles();

    test_keys(void); //Run the key generation algorithm

// Stop the cycle counter
    uint32_t end_time = DWT_GetCycles();

    // Calculate the elapsed time in cycles
    uint32_t elapsed_time = end_time - start_time;

    // Debug print elapsed cycles
    PRINTF("Elapsed cycles: %u\r\n", elapsed_time);

    // Calculate the time in microseconds (using integer arithmetic)
    uint32_t time_us = (elapsed_time * 1000000) / coreClockFrequency;
    PRINTF("Calculated time in us (integer): %u us\r\n", time_us);

    // Calculate the time in milliseconds (using integer arithmetic for verification)
    uint32_t time_ms_int = time_us / 1000;
    PRINTF("Calculated time in ms (integer): %u ms\r\n", time_ms_int);

    // Calculate the time in milliseconds (using float)
    float time_ms_float = (float)elapsed_time / coreClockFrequency * 1000.0f;
    PRINTF("Calculated time in ms (float): %.6f ms\r\n", time_ms_float);

while (1) {
            // Infinite loop
        }
}

